# How can I get the filename of a shared object in iOS share-extension

Tags: ios

Basically I want to retrieve files (e.g. pdf) from other apps (e.g. dropbox) to store and modify later.

I wrote a share-extension for that task and could iterate over NSExtensionItem's and can catch out my files - but I have no idea about their original filename.

I noticed that other apps got the filename - but they're called with the "open with" function in iOS.

So how I get the filename in my share-extension?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have the filename as lastPathComponent in the URL received:

```
    itemProvider!.first!.loadItemForTypeIdentifier(kUTTypeImage as String, options: nil, completionHandler: {
        (provider, error) in
        let url = provider as! NSURL

        println(url)

        let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url)

        let name = url.lastPathComponent!

        ...

        // Inform the host that we're done, so it un-blocks its UI. Note: Alternatively you could call super's -didSelectPost, which will similarly complete the extension context.
        self.extensionContext!.completeRequestReturningItems([], completionHandler: nil)
    })
```

Comment: This works well on iOS Share extension, but not on macos share extension. On MacOS share extension - provider is always returned as of type Data